# Sharepoint Search Result Display Template not showing custom managed metadata properties

Tags: search, search-results, display-template, people-search, promoted-results

I have expanded the **Item_Person** display template to include a couple of custom **managed metadata** properties. When this template is used in a **person-only search**, these properties gets data. However when I add a result block in a **everything** search, the properties gets no data. Any suggestions? Everything is mapped up correctly as it works in persons search..

Comment: Is the property in the PeopleIdx or the default content index?

Comment: The properties are in the PeopleIdx.

Comment: Have you visited the Result Type Rule page since publishing your Display Template? There is a mysterious "update" process that will display a yellow or green bar for you to trip an update. I see this from time to time. Also, did you map the rule to Everything or only People?

Comment: I mapped the rule to "All sources" and I did visit this page, but I do not remember seeing a bar of any color. Just to be sure, whats the url?

Comment: Also not all Results shows these properties, even though when I go to that persons delve page they are populated with data